# Openssl extension is not working

Tags: php, apache, openssl

I enable the `extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini` file. But Still its not working. I check it out in `phpinfo()`. But there I cant find the openssl extension.

Comment: Did you restart the Apache server after enabling it?

Comment: Where are you trying to enable this? On your server? On a local installation of XAMPP/MAMP/WAMP whatever?

Comment: Do you have the latest version (post Heartbleed) of openssl? Otherwise you are better off without!

Comment: I restart the wamp server.I m trying to enabling on server.On local m/c its works fine.